# Android and Bluthooth communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, communication

I want to communicate my circuit (PIC based) with Android devices.

I tried to communicate using Bluetooth but it always ask to pair.

I tried to search more on communication where problem is,pairing is required.

Can i achieve communication without pairing? I found that pairing of devices is an essential factor.

Can i use Bluetooth 2.1/ 3.0 versions for communication?

Can somebody recommended any specific Bluetooth modules at circuit end?

Hope to get the right answers

-Abhimoh

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that communication without pairing is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Bluegiga WT32 module with a PIC. It works well, and communicates through UART.

1. Pairing is required, but easy to do.
2. The WT32 uses 2.1